# How to select oldest date between two data

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to select the oldest date in my table but the problem is it's selecting the latest one. I was trying to select the one with more than 3 transactions. Here is my code for selecting the data:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTrxInventoryHeader GROUP BY storeId HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 LIMIT 1
```

It's selecting the latest date between two data.

Comment: Can you edit the question, providing sample data and desired results?  It is not clear from the explanation what you are trying to do, nor what columns in the table might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the oldest date in the table, then it is something like:

```
SELECT thedate
FROM tblTrxInventoryHeader
ORDER BY thedate ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want the oldest date with more than three transactions:

```
SELECT thedate
FROM tblTrxInventoryHeader
GROUP BY thedate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
ORDER BY thedate ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ORDER BY sql clause.

Answer (score -1):

You should include descending order